# В чем может быть проблема при передаче файлов по SFTP?

Tags: windows, sftp, autocad

Доброго времени.

Подключаюсь к папке на vps который крутит Ubuntu server 16.04. У пользователя отдельная группа, папка доступна только этой группе. Использую папку как сетевое хранилище. Из windows подключаюсь с помощью программы *SFTP Net Drive 2017*. Монтирую как логический диск. Всё работает отлично, кроме программы *Autodesk Invertor 2017* при сохранении документа он начинает сохраняться на скорости **1 кб\с**, при этом читает с нормальной скоростью.

В чём может быть проблема? Не пойму даже в какую сторону копать.

Comment: Т.е. если сохранить из автодеска на рабочий стол, а потом просто скопировать на этот диск, то всё ок?

Comment: Конечно. Скорость чтение\запись на sftp на одного пользователя настроена на 50 мб\с такая по сути и есть. Все программы которыми пользуюсь (офисные,  ide и т.д. работают нормально).